# Call a DLL with 'pointer' and structure (C++ -> VB.NET)

Tags: c++, vb.net, pointers, structure

I have problem about how I call a function on DLL to get data from a structure ...

Have a C++ example about how it's works the library, and I want to use it on vb.net

**Okay, this is the working c++ example:**

Declaration:

```c
BOOL (WINAPIV* MyFun)(DWORD start1, DWORD stop1, P_RESULT pResult, PDWORD pTpNum, myCALLBACK lpFunc) = NULL;
```

Call:

```c
// pStruc = RESULT structure
// TrpNum1, TrpNum is ULONG

ULONG TrpNum1=0;
MyFun(Start,Stop,pStruc+TrpNum,&TrpNum1,&myCB);
```

Callback:

```c
void __stdcall myCB (RESULT *pStruc)
{
    printf ("%.3f", (double)pStruc->val1);
    tpn++;
}
```

And of course, the structure:

```c
typedef struct {
    BOOL            mybool;
    DWORD           val1;       
    DWORD           val2;       
} RESULT, *P_RESULT;
```

**And this is my VB.net code (not working):**

```vb
Public Declare Auto Function MyFun Lib "\mydll.dll" ( _
        ByVal start As UInt32, _
        ByVal stop As UInt32, _
        ByRef Result As RESULT, ByRef pTpNum As UInt32, ByVal lpFunc As DlgCB) As Boolean

Public Sub CallMyFun()
    Dim Res As New RESULT
    Dim TpN As UInt32

    If MyFun(100, 200, Res, TpN, AddressOf myCB) Then
        SendDebug("OK")

    Else
        SendDebug("Failed!")
    End If

End Sub

Public Delegate Function DlgCB(ByVal Res As RESULT) As Boolean

Public Function myCB(ByVal Res As RESULT) As Boolean
    Debug.Print(Res.val1)
    Return True
End Function
```

Structure:

```vb
Public Structure RESULT
    Dim mybool As Boolean
    Dim val1 As UInt32
    Dim val2 As UInt32
End Structure
```

What is wrong guys?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** The error is this: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This often indicates that other memory is corrupt."

Also i do a small 'fix' in the code. Still don't work.

Comment: "Not working" is not a satisfying description. Add some info on exactly how it is not working (before doing that, change `ByVal Res As RESULT` to `ByRef Res As RESULT`).

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of problems here:

- myBool is an Integer, not a Boolean
- the Res variable almost surely can't be a local variable, make it a field
- possibly the same for TpN, it isn't clear if the C++ code stores the pointer
- for both, if the C++ code stores a pointer then the object needs to be pinned.  Marshaling yourself to memory allocated with Marshal.AllocHGlobal is much better
- the delegate you create with AddressOf is going to get garbage collected.  You need to store a reference in a field so that can't happen
- the callback should declare the parameter ByRef, not ByVal
- the C++ callback is void, you made it return a Boolean for some reason.

You need help to get this going, help that's a bit beyond with SO can provide.  Ask an experienced team member for assistance or hire a consultant.

Comment: My main problem is how to get the data in a array variable with a structure (RESULT) .. I think I need to use namespace Marshal, but I not have idea in how to do this in this case. Any help is welcome. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Your main problem is that you have a large number of problems.  Focusing on one of them isn't going to help you.

Comment: And you can help me with the right code to do this? I'm a bit desperate. :(

Comment: I can't, you didn't describe the C++ code well enough to allow anybody to write correct code.  Nor is SO a code writing service.  Can't say I didn't see this coming, that's why I added the last paragraph.  If you don't want to take that advice then I can only recommend that you work down the list of bullets one by one.  You'll be closer than you were yesterday.  Good luck with it!